# I have a captch php file i want to create recaptcha file can any one guide me

Tags: php

I have create a registration form with captcha but i required captcha that works client side but not server side, so that i want to develop recaptcha file that works on client side can any one help me please. Thanks in advance

MY captcha code is

```
session_start();
//Settings: You can customize the captcha here
$image_width = 120;
$image_height = 40;
$characters_on_image = 6;
$font = './monofont.ttf';

//The characters that can be used in the CAPTCHA code.
//avoid confusing characters (l 1 and i for example)
$possible_letters = '23456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz';
$random_dots = 0;
$random_lines = 20;
$captcha_text_color="0x142864";
$captcha_noice_color = "0x142864";

$code = ''; 

$i = 0;
while ($i < $characters_on_image) { 
    $code .= substr($possible_letters, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible_letters)-1), 1);
    $i++;
}   

$font_size = $image_height * 0.75;
$image = @imagecreate($image_width, $image_height); 

/* setting the background, text and noise colours here */
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

$arr_text_color = hexrgb($captcha_text_color);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, $arr_text_color['red'], 
        $arr_text_color['green'], $arr_text_color['blue']);

$arr_noice_color = hexrgb($captcha_noice_color);
$image_noise_color = imagecolorallocate($image, $arr_noice_color['red'], 
        $arr_noice_color['green'], $arr_noice_color['blue']);   

/* generating the dots randomly in background */
for( $i=0; $i<$random_dots; $i++ ) {
    imagefilledellipse($image, mt_rand(0,$image_width),
    mt_rand(0,$image_height), 2, 3, $image_noise_color);
}   

/* generating lines randomly in background of image */
for( $i=0; $i<$random_lines; $i++ ) {
    imageline($image, mt_rand(0,$image_width), mt_rand(0,$image_height),
    mt_rand(0,$image_width), mt_rand(0,$image_height), $image_noise_color);
}   

/* create a text box and add 6 letters code in it */
$textbox = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $font, $code); 
$x = ($image_width - $textbox[4])/2;
$y = ($image_height - $textbox[5])/2;
imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $text_color, $font , $code);    

/* Show captcha image in the page html page */
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');// defining the image type to be shown in browser widow
imagejpeg($image);//showing the image
imagedestroy($image);//destroying the image instance
$_SESSION['6_letters_code'] = $code;

function hexrgb ($hexstr)
{
    $int = hexdec($hexstr); 
    return array("red" => 0xFF & ($int >> 0x10),
               "green" => 0xFF & ($int >> 0x8),
               "blue" => 0xFF & $int);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement reCaptcha and replace your current system? Look at their docs: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#AJAX

Comment: You want a 100% client-side captcha? Doesn't that sort of negate the point of using a captcha? If all validation is done client side, server requests become immediately spoofable again...

Comment: i have many text fields in my registration form, before submitting the form entering captcha, entering wrong data of captcha  entire page turns into blank registration page, so that i requires client side validation

Comment: The purpose of captcha is to stop automated programs to exploit your website. A client side captcha can be spoofed (like DaveRandom and bl4de said) so client side validation won't guarantee that the user is a real person, because the spoofing may lead to the fact that the data of captcha will NEVER be wrong, client side-wise. Imagine that someone does that; and an automated program will complete thousands of registration forms a minute with correct hacked captcha validation, spamming your website, consuming your resources, etc.

Comment: ok fine, i will think in any other way

Answer (score 1):

You can't implement client-side recaptcha in PHP. Any captcha implemented on client-side (in JavaScript or something) is easy to break, so this is not good idea.

Comment: ok boss thankyou for your idea. I think instead implementing recaptcha in my application just make value to print after page load also.

Answer (score 0):

captcha validation cannot be done in client side. It can be done in server side only..